# Use mock db when testing with Robolectric and ORMLite

Tags: android, sqlite, gradle, ormlite, robolectric

I am working on an Android app that uses **OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper** to connect to the SQLite db.

```
public class MyDatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {
    ...

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydb.sqlite";
    private static MyDatabaseHelper helper = null;

    private MyDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, BuildConfig.DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public static synchronized MyDatabaseHelper getHelper(Context context) {
        if (helper == null) {
            helper = new MyDatabaseHelper(context);
        }
        return helper;
    }
}
```

To fetch data from the db, I have some provider classes, they use some DAO.

```
public class ProductsProvider {

    public static List<Products> getProducts(Context context) {
        MyDatabaseHelper helper = MyDatabaseHelper.getHelper(context);
        Dao<Product, String> daoProducts = helperDatabase.getProductDao();
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

I have in place Robolectric to test my code, but I am having hard time to understand how to use together Robolectric with ORMLite.
My idea is to have a mock database.sqlite, prefilled with the same structure and data I normally have, and use that for all my tests. For example, if I want to test the ProductsProvider class, I should do:

```
@RunWith(MyTestRunner.class)
public class ProductsProviderTest extends MyTestCase {

    @Test
    public void testDb() {
        List<Products> products = ProductsProvider.getProducts(getTestContext());
        assertNotNull(products);
        assertFalse(products.isEmpty());
    }
}
```

Notice that ProductsProvider.getProducts() will use MyDatabaseHelper, which will use the db in the standard location of the Android app, and not my local file.
How can modify my code for the tests to have the tests using a local db added as an **asset** or a **resource**, without touching the real code of the app?

Comment: Do these answers help? Seems to be a similar issue
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28321961/how-do-i-know-if-my-app-is-running-with-robolectric/28322189#28322189

Comment: Not really, I don't want to implement the last solution proposed, and with the comment below that, it is not clear how he managed to resolve the problem.
Even if I create a new class MyDatabaseHelperTest in the tests, I don't see how I can override the one in the main code, since my ProductsProvider is using the one in main code.

Comment: The answer I was referring to specifically was Eugen's. You can create a TestApplication that Robolectric will pickup and in there you can initialise a database helper specifically to load the data you need for your tests.

Comment: I will have to change the main code in any case then... I wanted to see if anyone had found another solution for that. But still... my DB instance will be in the Application class... how do I use it then in my helper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here how we are doing it.

1. We put sample DB file in `src/test/res` folder
2. We run next code before DB test:

   ```
   private void copyTestDatabase( String resourceDBName )
       throws URISyntaxException, IOException
   {
       String filePath = getClass().getResource( resourceDBName ).toURI().getPath();

       String destinationPath = new ContextWrapper( Robolectric.application.getApplicationContext() ).getDatabasePath(
           DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_NAME ).getAbsolutePath();

       Files.copy( new File( filePath ), new File( destinationPath ) );
   }
   ```

Be careful since these tests are super long

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean with "super long"? In term of time? Code complexity?

Comment: I meant timing. It takes up to 7 seconds sometimes

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who can't stand the 6-12-second startup times of Robolectric 3 + Gradle, the following works with Android's built-in JUnit4 tests (`DbHelper` extends `OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper`).

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class DbTest {

    private DbHelper dbHelper;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        Context context = new RenamingDelegatingContext(
                InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext(), "test_");
        dbHelper = new DbHelper(context);
    }
}
```

There are probably many optimisations you could make, but I can run a small, I/O-heavy suite that wipes the DB each time on GenyMotion in 2.5 seconds.

If you haven't been keeping up-to-date with it, I definitely recommend checking out what Google has done with its testing features recently. [The intro on the Robolectric site](http://robolectric.org/) is a flat-out lie at this point.