# Is there any way to add a method or code snippet in Android main project which only compiles with test project?

Tags: android, annotations, android-testing, android-proguard, android-instrumentation

I have one method in android app main project, which I want to compile only when I run Instrumented Unit Tests. For example:-

```
    Class MyActivity extends Activity {
     // some usual methods....

    // my method which I want to compile only when I run Instrumented test project
    void myInstrumentSpecificMethod() {....}
```

Is there any idea how can I make this method working only for test project and not for main project?
Is there any annotation framework for this, or Pro-Guard rules?

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html

Comment: Related question, I think the solution by Alex Florescu is the one you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28321961/how-do-i-know-if-my-app-is-running-with-robolectric. Though sometimes I do similar things, I agree with the disclaimers in those answers.